# Joining on unique ID and date range - must return 1 row

Tags: sql-server, join

In my calculated data layer, I am attempting to populate a Customer's postcode at the time of the order, a sub sample of the table being populated is as follows:

```
CustomerOrders
(
    CustomerID varchar(20),
    ...
    OrderDate date,
    ...
    CustomerPostcodeAtTimeOfOrder varchar(10)
)
```

This table is a join of the Customers table, the Orders table and the CustomerAddress table which looks like follows:

```
CustomerAddress
(
    CustomerID varchar(20),
    AddressType varchar(10),
    /*
    AddressDetails    
    */
    StartDate date,
    EndDate date,
    AddressRank int
)
```

It is quite conceivable that a customer may have recorded addresses of various types for a single date so the intention when populating the CustomerOrders table is to join as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Postcode
        FROM CustomerAddress ca
        WHERE ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN ca.StartDate AND ca.EndDate
        ORDER BY AddressRank
    )
```

However, the performance hit I am getting by adding this join to the query means that returning 1000 rows goes from taking 4 seconds to taking 106 seconds.

Just to note, I have added a non-clustered index on the Address table too. The definition of which is as below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX (IX_CustomerAddress)
ON CustomerAddress (StartDate, EndDate)
INCLUDE (AddressRank, CustomerID, Postcode)
```

I'm looking for any suggestions on the best way to tackle this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this will return results faster, but you can rewrite your query like this:

```
;WITH OrderAddress AS
(
    SELECT  o.*,
            ca.Postcode, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY AddressRank DESC)
    FROM CustomerAddress ca
    INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        AND o.OrderDate BETWEEN ca.StartDate AND ca.EndDate
)
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM OrderAddress
            WHERE RN = 1) o
    ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID;
```

You should also post the index definition on the Address table.

Comment: Having rewritten as a CTE, the query took 322 seconds to return the top 1000 rows so I'm assuming the addition of the ROW_NUMBER calculation took up more processing time that the original?

Comment: @AlexGrimsley That's most likely what happened. Anyway, that's quite a weird index definition for that table, it seems that `customerId` should be removed from the included columns and added as the first column key column instead